# How can I put messages from IBM MQ queue to objects?

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq, message-queue

I need to get messages from IBM MQ queue and put them into objects. So, I'm using the following code:

```
public MQMessage GetMessageFromQueue(string queueName)
{
    MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
    MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();

    var queueMngrForReading = new MQQueueManager(_managerName, _connectionParams);
    var queue = queueMngrForReading.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

    queue.Get(message, gmo);
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Message Data: " + message.ReadString(message.MessageLength));
    return message;
}
```

The problem is that when I call the method in Main using the following code:

```
MQClient mqClient = new MQClient();
mqClient.Connect(AppSettings.MQ.Manager);
string xml11 = mqClient.GetMessageFromQueue("PRQUEUE").ToString();
```

I get the values from my message displayed in Console, but the object xml11 gets the value "IBM.WMQ.MQMessage#013C8E0F".

How can I put the XML message in the object xml11?

Thanks.

Comment: Since your GetMessageFromQueue is returning a MQMessage, you need to call ReadString method to get message body. I am assuming the sender of the message is doing a WriteString to set the message body when sending messages. Refer here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm#q111220___mrw

Answer (score 0):

With `toString` you can not read the body of an `MQMessage`.

I would change `GetMessageFromQueue` like this:

```
public String GetMessageFromQueue(string queueName)
{
    MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
    MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();

    var queueMngrForReading = new MQQueueManager(_managerName, _connectionParams);
    var queue = queueMngrForReading.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

    queue.Get(message, gmo);
    String msgText = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Message Data: " + msgText)
    return msgText;
}
```

To simplify your code, I recommend using the XMS API, see [Developing XMS .NET applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/xms_tprog.html).